# Performing the Same mutate on all variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a 28-variable data frame, and I would like to mutate each variable in the same data frame with the same function. For example, add an extra column for each variable in the data frame where the new column is the log of the variable. So for example if I had

```
dataframe <- data.frame(X=data1, Y=data2, Z=data3)
```

I want a new data frame that contains X Y and Z, but also log(X), log(Y) and log(Z). This is easy enough to do using

```
mutate(dataframe, log(X)); mutate(dataframe(log(Y))
```

etc but for 28 variables (and multiple transformations on each variable - I want to get sqrt and ^2 of each too) it's a bit too much. I'm aware of the existance of mutate_all, but for some reason when I try to use that it replaces all the variables rather than adding new ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all` and specify the suffix in the `funs` so that it will create as a new column.  Otherwise, would replace the original with the output of the function

```
dataframe %>%
        mutate_all(funs(log = log(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option would be

```
df <- head(iris[1:2])
df[paste("log", names(df), sep = "_")] <- log(df)
df
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width log_Sepal.Length log_Sepal.Width
#1          5.1         3.5         1.629241        1.252763
#2          4.9         3.0         1.589235        1.098612
#3          4.7         3.2         1.547563        1.163151
#4          4.6         3.1         1.526056        1.131402
#5          5.0         3.6         1.609438        1.280934
#6          5.4         3.9         1.686399        1.360977
```